# Add image to a specific location using iText in Android

Tags: android, itext

I want to add image to a specific location in a PDF file using iText in Android. This is a fillable form and I have added textbox that is a place holder for the image and what I want to do is to get that textbox and image to it like this.

```
public class FormFill {
    public static void fill(AcroFields form, Person person) throws IOException, DocumentException{
        form.setField("firstname", person.getFirstName());
        form.setField("lastname", person.getLastName());
        form.setField("imagetextbox", "???");   

    }
```

I have the image uri like so

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(person.getImagePath());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656844/how-can-i-set-an-image-to-a-pdf-field-in-existing-pdf-file

Comment: Bruno thank you so much, however for some reason I am not able to get that example to work, I ended up using PdfContentByte

Answer (score 3):

try this.
i have used this function for add image in document.

```
public void addLogo(Document document) throws DocumentException {
    try { // Get user Settings GeneralSettings getUserSettings =

        Rectangle rectDoc = document.getPageSize();
        float width = rectDoc.getWidth();
        float height = rectDoc.getHeight();
        float imageStartX = width - document.rightMargin() - 315f;
        float imageStartY = height - document.topMargin() - 80f;

        System.gc();

        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("splashscreen.jpg");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);

        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        // PdfImage img = new PdfImage(arg0, arg1, arg2)

        // Converting byte array into image Image img =
        Image img = Image.getInstance(byteArray); // img.scalePercent(50);
        img.setAlignment(Image.TEXTWRAP);
        img.scaleAbsolute(200f, 50f);
        img.setAbsolutePosition(imageStartX, imageStartY); // Adding Image
        document.add(img);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, this solution looks great and I wish I can get it to work, I do not have an instance of a Document though, I have an instance of a Stamper. I will try to see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended adding the image like so

```
                Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
                overContent.addImage(image);
```